# Is it possible to use Sketch 3 to create 3d Card Effect?

Tags: 3d, sketch-app

How can one create a 3d card effect using Sketch App v3 ?

Something like this
[image]

For a simple scenario, I could create the following perspective effect,

[image]

but how can I create the 3d edges, as you see in the top image, it has some sort of 3d effect on the edges while mine (with arrows highlighting the edges) looks like a 2d image.

Is this actually possible in Sketch ? can you reference me to a resource so I can learn this technique?

Comment: Hello Ali, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Hi Vincent, I just added more comments describing my current result so far, I appreciate your comments

Answer (score 1):

You can create this type of effect with **Magic Mirror Plugin**.

It is available for demo...

http://magicmirror.design/

Comment: Hi Dhaval, I just added more comments describing my current result so far, I appreciate your comments